# Is it possible to add a UIGestureRecognizer to a View Controller rather than a view and if so, how?

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm making an app and part of it needs the ability to swipe between views on a single view controller. I want to use a gestureRecognizer but that would not work after the view has been changed.

Comment: Gestures apply to views. What about adding it to the view controller's view?

Comment: Like @rmaddy says, gestures (basic MVC) apply to views. If you can't just use the VC's view, maybe use a container view? One that has the views you wish to swipe between?